# Sofia SIP, response to Invite with no SDP

Tags: c++, sip, sofia-sip

My Sofia SIP application responds to Invite with no SDP like this

```
nua_respond(_nh, 200, "OK",

            SIPTAG_CONTENT_TYPE_STR("application/sdp"),
            NUTAG_OFFER_SENT(1),
            SOATAG_USER_SDP_STR("m=audio 1 RTP/AVP 0\n"
                                "a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000"),
            TAG_NULL());
```

However, ACK after this one is not processed, and I see "ACK Timeout". Are there any tags I'm missing?

Comment: Show the 200 Ok as it is sent to the network. "ACK is not processed"  means your application receives ACK but fails to handle it - In this case show the ACK also. Or no ACK is sent and this caused the timeout?

Comment: I'm using SIPP to generate calls, ACK is 100% sent. ACK event, apparently, is not passed to the event handler. Also, if I send INVITE with SDP, ACK is processed.

Comment: So run wireshark and catch the real sip traffic